# Radio button, Form, items, jspx

Tags: spring-roo, jspx

I have a create form in a jspx page. One of the fields in enum type.
I want to replace the select in the form with a radio button group.

It started with  :

```
 <field:select field="kyn" id="c_com_wop_fin_domain_Got_kyn" items="${kyns}" path="kyns" z="xxx="/>
```

I changed it to :

```
c:forEach var="enum" items="${gotkyns}" varStatus="pStatus">
        <input type="radio" name="gotkyns" value="${gotkyns}">${gotkyns}</input>
    </c:forEach>
```

I have two radio button but I would like to get the value of the enum in my radio buttons. How could I do that ?

My enum class looks like :

```
public enum GotKyn {

    Hundur, Tyk

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `radiobuton` or `radiobuttons` tags ( [Spring View technologies](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/view.html))

Import apropriate tag library and create data binding using

```
Hundur <form:radiobutton path="kyns" value="Hundur"/> <br/>
Tyk <form:radiobutton path="kyns" value="Tyk"/>
```

or

```
<form:radiobuttons path="kyns" items="${kynsValues}"/>
```

where `kynsValues` have to be populated in `Controller`. You pass in an Array, a List or a Map containing the available options in the "items" property ( [Providing a link to data from the model with @ModelAttribute](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html)).

```
@ModelAttribute("kynsValues")
public GotKyn[] populateGotKynsTypes() {
    return GotKyn.values();
}
```